# Desire2Learn Valence: Unenrolling users with hidden roles

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm having an issue with the **unenroll** call in Valence API for the users with roles that are **hidden**. I can unenroll the users with visible roles though.

My organization's wiki says that "If users are missing from the Classlist, their role in the course may be hidden". Is there any way to unenroll such a user? Am I missing some permissions to unenroll these users with hidden roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete a user enrollment using [`DELETE /d2l/api/lp/(version)/enrollments/orgUnits/(orgUnitId)/users/(userId)`](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#delete--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-enrollments-orgUnits-%28orgUnitId%29-users-%28userId%29) (or the action that removes the enrollment by specifying user ID first and then org unit ID), the calling user context must have permission to:

- See user enrollments in the first place (Users>View User Enrollments), at the *organization level*
- Search for the user role type(Users>Search for *RoleType*), at the *organization level*
- Enroll the user role type (Users>Enroll *RoleType*), at the *organization level*

Since the various `enrollments` actions are considered administrator-type actions, they use the "Users" role permissions at the organization level.

D2L has not currently provided *classlist level* API actions to unenroll users (so user contexts that would be able to un-enroll users from the classlist tool, within the web UI, often cannot do so using the Learning Framework API, unless the calling user's role has the organization-level permissions required to unenroll users).

Comment: Well, I just checked my account permissions. It does has both the above permissions you mentioned. One thing I noticed is that although I have permissions to view the roles but these roles are hidden somehow. After enrolling the user with such roles, I still can't see those users in get enrollments call. Probably, that's why I can't delete them. To me it looks like a bug or some feature that does not exists in D2L valence API. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ahh! Sorry; there's an additional permission needed. I was focussing on results that would come back with "no permission"; the calling context also has to be able to search for the role type at the org level to actually find the enrollment in the first place. I have confirmed that this call functions as stated with a calling user having _only_ those three permission settings, acting on an enrolled user in a course offering that does _not_ appear in the classlist.

Comment: Yup. That was it. The permission to search for that role did the trick.